# Recursively rendering component

Tags: reactjs

How do you render recursive lists using React? lets say you have a list data like

```
{
    "list": [
        "Parent",
        "subList": [
            {
                "First Child",
                "subList": [
                    {
                        "Grand Child 1-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Grand Child 1-2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Second Child",
                "subList": [
                    {
                        "Grand Child 2-1",
                        "sublist": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

How would you write a recursive map function to render indented sublists? Below is my attempt but I would like to make it recursively.

```
renderCheckboxRows = (list) => {
    list.map((filter, index) => {

        let content = <FilterRow key={index} {...filter} />;
        let subListContent = [];

        if (filter.subList && filter.subList.length > 0) {
            filter.subList.map((filter, index) => {
                subListContent.push(<FilterRow key={index} {...filter} />);
            });
        }
        return (content + subListContent);
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to get an answer to your question.
If yes, Please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510043/recursive-rendering-of-components-at-all-levels

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it by introducing a dedicated component for that purpose.

Lets name it `Node`. Its usage will be as follows:

```
<Node caption={root.caption} children={root.children}/>
```

Then inside `Node.render`:

```
render()
{
    var children = [];

    children = this.props.children.map((c) =>
    {
        return <Node caption={c.caption} children={c.children}>
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.props.caption}</div>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is just a draft example and instead of `divs` you will have your own components, but it illustrates the idea.